# Finding all combinations of length k that has at least one of the pairs of T is in it

Tags: sets, polynomial-time

Let there be a list of $n$ elements $S$. Let $T$ be a set with $m$ elements ($m \leq nC2$), with each element in $T$ being a pair of distinct elements of $S$. For $k\geq2$, is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find the number of combinations of length $k$ of the elements of $S$ that at least one of the elements of $T$ is a subset of it?

This is the same as asking: For all combinations of $S$ of length $k$, how many have any of its subsets of length $2$ in $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a monotone 2SAT formula — that is, each clause is a disjunction of two *positive* literals. You can think of the variables as your set $S$ and of the clauses as your set $T$. A falsifying assignment corresponds to a choice of elements from $S$ (the elements assigned false) that contains one of the subsets in $T$.

If you could solve your problem, then by going over all values of $k$, you could count the number of falsifying assignments, and so the number of satisfying assignment. Yet #Monotone-2SAT is #P-complete. See for example Fournier and Malod, [Universal relations and #P-completeness](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eherve.fournier/publications/universal.pdf).